# Windows Server 2008 on Amazon EC2 - Unexpected restart (BSOD)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008, bsod

I'm having trouble with a Windows 2008 Server running on Amazon EC2. A few times a day (2-3 times, maybe more), I get an unexpected restart (BSOD), the server reboots and I receive this message: bluescreen event 41 task 63 code 209.

This issue appeared out of the sudden, I haven't change any of the settings.

Comment: There may be an issue with the host. Stop your instance completely and start it again. This will assign your instance to a new host. Keep in mind that if you are using instance storage, you will loose any data contained on the instance storage volumes (Back data up to EBS volumes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams the error was triggered because of a LAN driver installed on that machine. After an upgrade, the issue was solved.